# Code from fiddle doesn't work locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found a simply tooltip in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6L9j0v5y/1 and tried to use it locally but something goes wrong. I copied http://jsfiddle.net/6L9j0v5y/1/show frame source as well but there is the same effect(on page is only button and nothing happens when it is clicked).

I create file(by copying):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <style type="text/css">
        [data-style=mypops] + .popover {
        background: #4194ca;
        }
        [data-style=mypops] + .popover.bottom .arrow:after {
            border-bottom-color: #4194ca;
        }
        [data-style=mypops] + .popover-content {
        }
        .popovermenu {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        .popovermenu li {
        }
        .popovermenu li a {
            color: #fff;
        }
    </style>
    <title></title>
    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
        $(window).load(function(){
        $("#Pops").popover({
            html: true,
            content: function () {
                return $('#popover-content').html();
            }
        });
        });//]]> 
    </script>
</head>

<body>
  <br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <button tabindex="0" class="btn btn-default" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="bottom" id="Pops" data-style="mypops">Click Me</button>
    <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
        <ul class="popovermenu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

  <script>
  // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
  if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
    window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
      height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
      slug: "6L9j0v5y"
    }], "*")
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

There is no error in console, how is it possible to check why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when on a local environment it treats the resource URLs as local files because it doesn't have the `http` / `https` protocols in front of the URLs.

*It's not incorrect in doing that, **when on a server it'll work fine***, but locally it causes problems. Change the scripts to the following and it'll work fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: i put your code in my html file and page doesn't load (problem is for `code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js`, I change this line by `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>` and now page is loaded correctly but there is the same problem(nothing happens when click on button)

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't load? It worked perfectly fine when tested locally on my machine.

Comment: I tried again and it works, probably that was my bad, im sorry and thank you very much for your help